# Angular 2 and Ionic 2: Reusable component list

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, components, ionic2

I have a list that I will reuse on more than one page. For this, I decided to create a separate component just for it. But when I use this component inside another nothing happens, the screen goes blank.

App module:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { EventsList } from '../components/events-list/events-list.component';
import { TestPage } from '../components/test-page/test-page.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    EventsList,
    TestPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    EventsList,
    TestPage
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

TestPage (I am using to test the reusable component):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'test-page.html'
})
export class TestPage {

  events: any[] = [...]; // Here I use some dummy

}
```

TestPage template:

```
<ion-content>
  <events-list [events]="events"></events-list>
</ion-content>
```

EventsList (The reusable component):

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'events-list',
  templateUrl: 'events-list.html'
})
export class EventsList {

  @Input() events: any[];

}
```

EventsList template:

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="events" approxItemHeight="'411px'">

  <ion-card *virtualItem="let event">

    <ion-img [src]="(event.cover ? event.cover.source : 'http://ionicframework.com/dist/preview-app/www/assets/img/advance-card-map-mario.png')" class="event-cover"></ion-img>

    <ion-fab right top>
      <button [ngSwitch]="event.rsvp_status" ion-fab>
          <ion-icon *ngSwitchCase="'attending'" name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon *ngSwitchCase="'interested' || 'maybe'" name="star"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon *ngSwitchCase="'declined'" name="close"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon *ngSwitchCase="'not_replied'" name="help"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon *ngSwitchDefault name="help"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-fab>

    <ion-item class="event-header">
      <h2 class="event-name">{{ event.name }}</h2>
      <p>
        <ion-icon name="clock"></ion-icon>
        {{ event.start_time | amCalendar }}
      </p>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-left>
        <ion-img [src]="(event.owner.picture ? event.owner.picture.data.url : 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar?d=mm&s=140')"></ion-img>
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2 class="subscription-name">{{ event.owner.name }}</h2>
      <p *ngIf="event.place">
        <ion-icon name="pin"></ion-icon>
        {{ event.place.name || event.place.location.street || 'Local sem nome' }}
      </p>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item class="event-footer">
      <span item-left>{{ event.attending_count }}</span>
      <span item-left>
            <ion-icon name="checkmark" class="event-attending"></ion-icon>
        </span>
      <span item-left>745</span>
      <span item-left>
            <ion-icon name="star" class="event-interested"></ion-icon>
        </span>
      <button ion-button icon-left clear item-right>
          <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
          DETALHES
        </button>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-card>

</ion-list>
```

Some system informations:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.17
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.45
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.2.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to wrap TestePage template inside <ion-content>. Now does not give error, but also shows nothing.

Comment: did you try with web console to figure out where the problem happens?

Comment: Everything looks okay just from glancing, why don't you setup a plunkr (there's a few ionic2 templates) so we can figure exactly what's up

Comment: I could not reproduce the error in plunkr... In the list component constructor when trying to log this.events it returns undefined. The funny thing is that if I add {{ events | json }} somewhere in the list component html everything works perfectly. What can it be?